# Tensorflow not properly utilising GPUs on ubuntu server 22.10

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu, nvidia

I'm doing some training on 4 GTX6000

```
$root@localhost:~# nvidia-smi
Fri Nov 18 17:42:26 2022       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 510.85.02    Driver Version: 510.85.02    CUDA Version: 11.6     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  Quadro RTX 6000     Off  | 00000000:00:02.0 Off |                  Off |
| 34%   30C    P8    12W / 260W |  19126MiB / 24576MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   1  Quadro RTX 6000     Off  | 00000000:00:03.0 Off |                  Off |
| 33%   29C    P8    13W / 260W |    338MiB / 24576MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   2  Quadro RTX 6000     Off  | 00000000:00:04.0 Off |                  Off |
| 36%   27C    P8    17W / 260W |    338MiB / 24576MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   3  Quadro RTX 6000     Off  | 00000000:00:05.0 Off |                  Off |
| 34%   26C    P8     8W / 260W |    338MiB / 24576MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A     64913      C   /usr/bin/python3                19123MiB |
|    1   N/A  N/A     64913      C   /usr/bin/python3                  335MiB |
|    2   N/A  N/A     64913      C   /usr/bin/python3                  335MiB |
|    3   N/A  N/A     64913      C   /usr/bin/python3                  335MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

The python process seems to only only be utilising 1 gpu

When I do "show_gpu_devices" it shows all 4 GPUs

> `gpu_devices: [PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:GPU:0', device_type='GPU'), PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:GPU:1', device_type='GPU'), PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:GPU:2', device_type='GPU'), PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:GPU:3', device_type='GPU')]`

additionally, the GPU memory usage seems to just keep going up until the python process everntually crashes - after the app crashes, the GPu memory stays utilised

Anyone know what could be the issue?

I spent ages setting up my drivers for ubuntu (server) yesterday (libcudnn8, nvidia-driver, nvididia-dkms, etc)

One thing I keep seeing still, is these logs on startup:

```
2022-11-18 17:32:03.548634: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:193] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX2 AVX512F AVX512_VNNI FMA
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2022-11-18 17:32:03.708046: I tensorflow/core/util/util.cc:169] oneDNN custom operations are on. You may see slightly different numerical results due to floating-point round-off errors from different computation orders. To turn them off, set the environment variable `TF_ENABLE_ONEDNN_OPTS=0`.
2022-11-18 17:32:03.758900: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_blas.cc:2981] Unable to register cuBLAS factory: Attempting to register factory for plugin cuBLAS when one has already been registered
2022-11-18 17:32:04.460871: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'libnvinfer.so.7'; dlerror: libnvinfer.so.7: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2022-11-18 17:32:04.461221: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'libnvinfer_plugin.so.7'; dlerror: libnvinfer_plugin.so.7: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2022-11-18 17:32:04.461346: W tensorflow/compiler/tf2tensorrt/utils/py_utils.cc:38] TF-TRT Warning: Cannot dlopen some TensorRT libraries. If you would like to use Nvidia GPU with TensorRT, please make sure the missing libraries mentioned above are installed properly.
2022-11-18 17:32:05.216241: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:980] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2022-11-18 17:32:05.216921: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:980] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2022-11-18 17:32:05.217432: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:980] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2022-11-18 17:32:05.217889: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:980] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2022-11-18 17:32:05.318684: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:980] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
```

Crash error:

```
2022-11-18 17:37:31.246166: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:479] Allocator (GPU_0_bfc) ran out of memory trying to allocate 7.62GiB (rounded to 8185780992)requested by op gradients/cond_grad/If/then/_0
```

Comment: Do you use `tf.distribute` API to train your model? Refer-https://keras.io/guides/distributed_training/

Comment: @V.M Thanks, that fixed one issue, theres still seems to be some missing dynamic lib/driver, as well as the memory leak / overflow

Comment: You may need to check the tensorflow version and coda compatibility. You may to reinstall tensorflow.